recyclerView disappear when return to fragement
when i start the fragment first the recyclerView works fine but when i switch to other fragments or activities then return back the other views works fine but the flock cards recyclerView disappears (when i resume the app for example when i enter another app than resume my app the flock recyclerView returns to normal)
gif describe the issue
package com.example.firma;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;


public class FarmFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView chickenTxt;
    TextView food;
    TextView name;

    ConstraintLayout layout;
    View view;
    CollectionReference siloRef;

    ImageView silos,flocks;

    RecyclerView recyclerViewFlocks;
    CardFlockAdapter flockAdapter;
    CollectionReference flockRef;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_farm, container, false);
        chickenTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        food = view.findViewById(R.id.textView24);
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        recyclerViewSIlos = view.findViewById(R.id.siloCards);
        silos = view.findViewById(R.id.silos_arrow);
        flocks = view.findViewById(R.id.flocks_arrow);

        recyclerViewFlocks = view.findViewById(R.id.flockCards); // Replace with the appropriate view ID

        flockRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText()).collection("flocks");

        setupRecyclerFlocks(flockRef);


        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText()).collection("flocks")
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    int chicken=0;
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (documentSnapshot.contains("number")) {
                            chicken+=Integer.parseInt(documentSnapshot.getString("number"));
                        }
                    }
                    chickenTxt.setText(Integer.toString(chicken));
                });

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText()).collection("silos")
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    double current=0.0;
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (documentSnapshot.contains("current")) {
                            current+=Double.parseDouble(documentSnapshot.getString("current"));
                        }
                    }
                    String formattedCurrent = String.format("%.2f", current);
                    food.setText(formattedCurrent);
                    hideLoading();
                });

        name.setText(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText());
        siloRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText()).collection("silos");
        setupRecyclerSilo(siloRef);



        return  view;
    }



    private void hideLoading() {
    }
    RecyclerView recyclerViewSIlos;
    cardSiloAdapter siloAdapter;

    public void setupRecyclerSilo(CollectionReference query) {
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SiloItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<SiloItem>()
                .setQuery(query, SiloItem.class)
                .build();

        siloAdapter = new cardSiloAdapter(options);
        recyclerViewSIlos.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerSilo = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerViewSIlos.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerSilo);
        recyclerViewSIlos.setAdapter(siloAdapter);
    }



    private void setupRecyclerFlocks(CollectionReference query) {
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<CardFlockModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<CardFlockModel>()
                .setQuery(query, CardFlockModel.class)
                .build();

        flockAdapter = new CardFlockAdapter(options);
        recyclerViewFlocks.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerFlocks = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerViewFlocks.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerFlocks);
        recyclerViewFlocks.setAdapter(flockAdapter);
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        siloAdapter.startListening();
        flockAdapter.startListening(); // Add this line
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        siloAdapter.stopListening();
        flockAdapter.stopListening(); // Add this line
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        siloAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        flockAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Add this line
    }

}

package com.example.firma;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.firma.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityHomeBinding activityHomeBinding;

    Menu bottomMenu;
    MenuItem farm;
    String food = "0";
    MenuItem house;
    MenuItem silo;
    MenuItem finance;
    int j=0;

    List<String> menuItemDataList;
    List<String> ids;
    Button button;
    volatile Boolean fetched=false;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    ListView lst;
    private boolean hasFlocks = false;




    private void fetchFarmsFromFirestore() {
        Log.i("fetching", "Before fetching data from Firestore");
        // Assuming your Firestore collection is named "farms"
        CollectionReference farmsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());


        String selectedItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedItem");
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            button.setText(selectedItem);
            dailytest();
            // Set other data based on the selected item
        }



        // Fetch data from Firestore
        farmsRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
            menuItemDataList = new ArrayList<>();
            ids = new ArrayList<>();

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                // Parse data and add items to your list
                String farmName = documentSnapshot.getString("name");
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();

                // Create a Menu-ItemData object and add it to the list
                assert farmName != null;
                menuItemDataList.add(farmName);
                ids.add(id);
                Log.i("fetching", menuItemDataList.toString());
            }
            if (menuItemDataList != null && menuItemDataList.size() > 0 && selectedItem == null) {
                button.setText(menuItemDataList.get(0));
                ButtonTextHolder.setButtonText(ids.get(0));
                Log.i("fetching2", menuItemDataList.toString());

                Log.i("here","1");

                dailytest();

            } else {
                // Handle the case where menuItemDataList is empty or null
                // You may want to set a default value or handle it accordingly
            }
            fetched = true;

        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            // Handle failure to fetch data from Firestore
            Log.e(TAG, "Error fetching data from Firestore", e);
        });

    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void showPopupWindow() {
        Log.i("window", "showing");
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.farms_window, null);

        // Find the ListView
        lst = container.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter for the ListView
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(HomeActivity.this, R.layout.listview_customized, menuItemDataList);
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Calculate the total height of the ListView
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int listItemHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.list_item_height);
        int maxItemsToShow = Math.min(adapter.getCount(), 3); // Maximum of 3 items visible without scrolling
        for (int i = 0; i < maxItemsToShow; i++) {
            totalHeight += listItemHeight;
        }

        // Set the height of the ListView to its total content height
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lst.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight;
        lst.setLayoutParams(params);

        // Create the PopupWindow
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 350, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

        // Show the PopupWindow
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(button, 0, 0, Gravity.CENTER);

        // Set an item click listener for the ListView
        lst.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, l) -> {

            String selectedFarmName = menuItemDataList.get(position);
            String selectedFarmId = ids.get(position);

            ButtonTextHolder.setButtonText(selectedFarmId);
            popupWindow.dismiss();

            // Restart HomeActivity with the selected item
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedItem", selectedFarmName);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish(); // Finish the current activity to avoid stacking

            // Dismiss the PopupWindow
        });

        // Dismiss the PopupWindow when touching outside
        container.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return false;
        });
    }


    public void dailytest(){
        Log.i("here","2");
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        String todaysdate = dateFormat.format(date);
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText())
                .collection("flocks")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        hasFlocks = false;
                    } else {
                        hasFlocks = true;
                        // ... rest of the code ...
                    }
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        String last = documentSnapshot.getString("last");
                        String first = documentSnapshot.getString("first");
                        String weight = documentSnapshot.getString("weight");
                        food = documentSnapshot.getString("food");
                        String water = documentSnapshot.getString("water");
                        String number = documentSnapshot.getString("number");
                        String silo = documentSnapshot.getString("silo");
                        Log.i("silo","1"+silo);
                        LocalDate todaysLocalDate = LocalDate.now();
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        LocalDate lastLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(last, formatter);
                        LocalDate firstLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(first, formatter);
                        Log.i("here","2.5");

                        // Calculate the difference in days
                        long dayDifference = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(lastLocalDate, todaysLocalDate);
                        long daynbr = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstLocalDate, todaysLocalDate);
                        long dday = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstLocalDate, lastLocalDate);
                        Log.i("here","2.6");

                        if (dayDifference != 0) {
                            Map<String, Object> stats = new HashMap<>();
                            Map<String, Object> lasted = new HashMap<>();
                            lasted.put("last", todaysLocalDate.format(formatter));
                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                    .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText())
                                    .collection("flocks")
                                    .document(documentSnapshot.getId())
                                    .update(lasted);
                            j=0;
                            for (long i = dday + 1; i <= daynbr; i++) {
                                j++;
                                LocalDate currentLocalDate = firstLocalDate.plusDays(i);
                                stats.put("day", i);
                                stats.put("sday",Long.toString(i));
                                stats.put("date", currentLocalDate.format(formatter));
                                stats.put("dead", "0");
                                stats.put("weight", weight);
                                stats.put("feed", food);
                                stats.put("water", water);
                                stats.put("price", "0.0");
                                stats.put("sold", "0");
                                stats.put("number", number);
                                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                        .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText())
                                        .collection("flocks")
                                        .document(documentSnapshot.getId())
                                        .collection("stats")
                                        .document("day " + i)
                                        .set(stats);
                            }
                            Log.i("silo","1"+silo);
                            assert silo != null;
                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                    .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText()).collection("silos").document(silo).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                            String currStr = documentSnapshot.getString("current");
                                            if (currStr != null) {
                                                double curr = Double.parseDouble(currStr);
                                                double set = Double.parseDouble(food) * j;
                                                double result = curr - set;
                                                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                                        .document(ButtonTextHolder.getButtonText()).collection("silos").document(silo).update("current",Double.toString(result));
                                            }


                                        }
                                    });


                        }
                        replaceFragment(new FarmFragment());
                        Log.i("here","3");

                    }
                }) .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (!hasFlocks) {
                        replaceFragment(new FarmFragment());
                    }
                });
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        activityHomeBinding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityHomeBinding.getRoot());

        // Set up the toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(activityHomeBinding.toolbar);

        // Set navigation icon click listener
        activityHomeBinding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> activityHomeBinding.drawerLayout.open());


        // Obtain the Menu object from BottomNavigationView
        bottomMenu = activityHomeBinding.bottomNavigationView.getMenu();

        activityHomeBinding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
                menuItem.setCheckable(false);
                activityHomeBinding.drawerLayout.close();
                String title = menuItem.getTitle().toString();
                switch (title) {
                    case "Suppliers":
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SupplierActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case "Workers":
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkerActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);

                        break;
                    case "Edit farm":
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), edit_farm.class);
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        break;
                    case "Edit house":
                        Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), edit_house.class);
                        startActivity(intent4);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Initialize menu items after inflating the layout
        farm = bottomMenu.findItem(R.id.home);
        house = bottomMenu.findItem(R.id.house);
        silo = bottomMenu.findItem(R.id.silo);
        finance = bottomMenu.findItem(R.id.finance);

        button = findViewById(R.id.menu_button);

        // Set button click listener
        button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            // Display popup window
            showPopupWindow();
            Log.i("btn","clickeddd");
        });


        fetchFarmsFromFirestore();

        //fragments

        setContentView(activityHomeBinding.getRoot());
        activityHomeBinding.bottomNavigationView.setBackground(null);
        activityHomeBinding.bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if(item.getItemId()==R.id.home){
                replaceFragment(new FarmFragment());
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.farm_purple);
                item.setEnabled(false);
                house.setEnabled(true);
                silo.setEnabled(true);
                finance.setEnabled(true);
                house.setIcon(R.drawable.gris_flock);
                silo.setIcon(R.drawable.silo_gris);
                finance.setIcon(R.drawable.dollar_gris);
            } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.house) {
                replaceFragment(new HouseFragment());
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.group_30);
                item.setEnabled(false);
                farm.setEnabled(true);
                silo.setEnabled(true);
                finance.setEnabled(true);
                farm.setIcon(R.drawable.farm_gris);
                silo.setIcon(R.drawable.silo_gris);
                finance.setIcon(R.drawable.dollar_gris);
            } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.silo) {
                replaceFragment(new SiloFragment());
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.silo_purple);
                item.setEnabled(false);
                house.setEnabled(true);
                farm.setEnabled(true);
                finance.setEnabled(true);
                farm.setIcon(R.drawable.farm_gris);
                house.setIcon(R.drawable.gris_flock);
                finance.setIcon(R.drawable.dollar_gris);
            } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.finance) {
                replaceFragment(new FinanceFragment());
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.dollara_purple);
                item.setEnabled(false);
                house.setEnabled(true);
                silo.setEnabled(true);
                farm.setEnabled(true);
                farm.setIcon(R.drawable.farm_gris);
                silo.setIcon(R.drawable.silo_gris);
                house.setIcon(R.drawable.gris_flock);
            }

            return true;
        });
        //fin fragments

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------

        // dialog
        activityHomeBinding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showBottomDialog();
            }
        });

    }
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // Check if the fragment is already added
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_layout);

        // If the fragment is already added, do nothing
        if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment.getClass().equals(fragment.getClass())) {
            return;
        }

        // If the fragment is not added, replace it
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("farm", button.getText().toString());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_layout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }




   enter image description here
    private void showBottomDialog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout);

        // hado views li rahom fl dialog
        LinearLayout creatFarm = dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutFarm);
        LinearLayout creatHouse = dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutHouse);
        LinearLayout createSilo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutSilo);
        LinearLayout createFlock = dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutflock);
        ImageView cancelButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);


        creatFarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                        Create_Farm_activity.class));
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Create a farm is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
       
        createFlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Create_Flock_activity.class);
                i.putExtra("farmName",button.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Create a house is Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        
        createSilo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), create_silo.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Go create silo is Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        creatHouse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Create_house_activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Go create house is Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        //button li tgle3 dialog
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        // design dialog programatically (tba3t handi dar haka)
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        
    }



}

i removed all flocks code including the flock adapter and flock model , and creating new ones but it didn't work

try to save options data in global variable
FirestoreRecyclerOptions options ;
options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder()
.setQuery(query, CardFlockModel.class)
.build();

If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted almost 700 (seven hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's way too much for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question.

Please also respond using @AlexMamo

it looks like that you are setting the recyclerView when the view is created, and when you navigate back it some time to fetch the data. so you could use a loader which shows at the time of fetching data, OR you can use viewModel to store the fetched data, as it will preserve your data as long as the fragement is active
